# Windows files stuck in Ubuntu trash

Tags: delete, trash

I have a dual boot (ubuntu/windows8.1) system. In ubuntu's file manager, popped into the windows partition and deleted a lot of files in some of the user's directories. However, I couldn't delete them because I didn't have the right permissions. So I booted Windows and deleted the user accounts from there, including the files.

However, back in my ubuntu system, there are lots of files in the trash that I now cannot delete nor restore. I also tried to use the command line, but there is nothing in `./local/share/Trash/files`.

How can I get rid of the ghost files in my ubuntu trash?

Thanks.

Comment: What commands did you use?  What errors are you getting? Did you use sudo?

Comment: Just the `ls` command in `./local/share/Trash/files`, but it's sorted now.

Answer (score 0):

So I tried to delete the files from the window manager with the empty trash button, but what worked for me was right clicking the trash icon and running Empty trash. Files are now not appearing in the trash folder.